# Values from database into hashmap gives repeating sequence of key and values

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve data from my database and put it in hashmaps and add the hashmaps to location objects in a list of location objects named listOfLocations.
My input is a list of 128 location objects with property name, which I use to find the species found at those locations in the database.
From the database I retrieve the location name and the diatom species of that location.
When I go through the data in rs.next, I check if the species was in the initial input of my program (diatomArray) and give the hashmap key a value of present or not based on that.
But the problem is, I end up with all diatomHashmaps being the same. They all contain the same keys and values.
I have checked what is in rs.getString(1) and rs.getString(2) and that isn't the same repeating sequence as I'm observing in the diatomHashmap.
I have been staring at my code for hours, but I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. I hope someone can point out my fault in the logics.

```
try (Connection connection = DbConnection.getConnection()) {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    String query = "SELECT l.name, d.species " +
            "FROM Entry e " +
            "INNER JOIN Location l ON l.name = e.name " +
            "INNER JOIN Diatom d ON d.taxonKey = e.taxonKey " +
            "WHERE d.species != '' AND l.name IN ";
    assert connection != null;
    StringBuilder whereIn = new StringBuilder("(?");
    //make as many placeholders as there are locations in the input.
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfLocations.size() - 1; ++i) {
        whereIn.append(", ?");
    }
    //ORDER BY location.name so I can go through all diatoms per location.
    whereIn.append(") ORDER BY l.name");
    query += whereIn.toString();
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    for (int i = 1; i <= listOfLocations.size(); ++i) {
        preparedStatement.setString(i, listOfLocations.get(i - 1).getName());
    }
    //currentLocation will keep track of which location is currently being iterated.
    String currentLocation = "";
    int counter = 0;
    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    HashMap<String, String> diatomHashmap = new HashMap<>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        //if currentLocation is not set yet (only the first location), set currentLocation.
        if (currentLocation.equals("")) {
            currentLocation = rs.getString(1);
        }
        //if statement, if I'm still on the currentLocation, add the species to the diatomHashmap.
        //Present or notPresent based on input (diatomArray).
        if (currentLocation.equals(rs.getString(1))) {
            if (diatomArray.contains(rs.getString(2))) {
                diatomHashmap.put(rs.getString(2), "Present");
            } else {
                diatomHashmap.put(rs.getString(2), "notPresent");
            }
        } else {
            //else will be called when currentLocation does NOT equal the location in rs.getString(1).
            //add the made diatomHashmap to Location object in listOfLocations (list of Location objects).
            listOfLocations.get(counter).setDiatoms(diatomHashmap);
            //set currentLocation to the new location being iterated.
            currentLocation = rs.getString(1);
            //increase counter so we move to the next Location object in listOfLocation.
            counter++;
            //clear hashmap to start adding new species to the current location.
            diatomHashmap.clear();
            //makes the first new entry in the hashmap.
            if (diatomArray.contains(rs.getString(2))) {
                diatomHashmap.put(rs.getString(2), "Present");
            } else {
                diatomHashmap.put(rs.getString(2), "notPresent");
            }
        }
    }
    //one last setDiatoms because the last location will never reach the else statement.
    listOfLocations.get(counter).setDiatoms(diatomHashmap);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HashMap<String, String> diatomHashmap = new HashMap<>();
```

Looks you defined only one diatomHashmap. all `setDiatoms` sets the same object.

> listOfLocations.get(counter).setDiatoms(diatomHashmap);`

Comment: But as long as currentLocation is the same, it should add to the hashmap, the moment I move to the next location I set the diatomhashmap to the location object I'm currently at and then I clear the hashmap, so I can start adding species to the hashmap again. So can you explain why all setdiatoms would set the same object?

Comment: In java the `object variables` are refernce, not value. setDiatoms(diatomHashmap); does not copy the values. it references the same hashmap always. replace `diatomHashmap.clear();` with `diatomHashmap = new HashMap<>();` .